# Creation alerts in Custom Process Template for TFS2015

Tags: tfs

I am creating Custom Process Template for TFS2015. I want that all firutes will be configured automaticaly. One feature what I need it is that some alerts was set up automaticaly when I create new project.

Does it possible that I change standart CMMI template that when I create project some alerts set up automaticaly? If yes, could you give example of configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Process templates define the objects and processes available to you when you create a team project. [By customizing a process template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243782.aspx), you customize one of more objects or processes. Common types of customizations you can make include:

- Add a new field to an existing work item types (WIT)
- Modify the pick list of values for a field
- Change the workflow─States, Reasons, Transitions, Actions─of an existing work item type
- Edit the layout of a work item form
- Add or remove a work item type
- Change process configuration or defaults associated with Agile tools

Instead of changing process template, you need to use [Alert setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/track/alerts-and-notifications) to receive email notifications for alerts that you define. Choose from one of the several alert types listed:

[image]